# Directional network graph in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts

Is there a way to create a directional network graph using d3js or highcharts .I was able to create a unidirectional network graph on high chart .

What I have with my highchart code is

[image]

What I need is

[image]

I am not sure if this is possible with highchart or d3js ,I searched through their library but couldn't find way to add directional arrows . Anyone if has worked on it can please advice .  I cant use neo4j because my Backend DB is elasticsearch and I can't use neo4J .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with Highcharts but requires some customization. You can for example wrap the `getLinkPath` method and generate a path with an arrow.

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.networkgraph.prototype.pointClass.prototype, 'getLinkPath', function(proceed) {
    return [...] // path;
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pk8y49qw/

Or add an arrow to already existing paths.

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vk81xbn3/

**Useful threads:**

- https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45331
- https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12781

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Oh my god !! thank you so much , I wanted to implement this on highcharts .Its very helpful for me . Thank u so much

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the easiest thing to do would be to use [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz).

```js
let dotSource = `digraph{
  node [
    style=filled;
  ]
  A [fillcolor=red; fontcolor=black];
  B [fillcolor=green; fontcolor=white];
  C [fillcolor=black; fontcolor=white];
  D [fillcolor=orange; fontcolor=white];
  A -> B;
  B -> C;
  B -> D
}`
d3.select("#graph").graphviz()
    .engine('neato')
    .renderDot(dotSource);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-graphviz/5.0.2/d3-graphviz.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph" style="text-align: center;"></div>
```

There are a ton of options to lay out and/or style the graph.

Comment: perfect ...thank u so much ..let me try it .